# Method for checking the boolean value of a RemoteView switch?

Tags: java, android, remoteview

Was wondering if there was something like .ischecked when it comes to RemoteView switches?

I can set it to false or true, no problem, but checking its value I'm having trouble with.

```
 contentView.setBoolean(R.id.notification_switch, "setChecked", false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but there are no means of reading the contents of any `RemoteViews` widgets.

Comment: So whats the work around? I know its possible, I've seen it in apps already. I have a service class that needs to start when the toggle is in the ON position and a stop service class to run when the toggle is in the OFF position.

Comment: @LinS: I see no evidence that `RemoteViews` actually supports `Switch` or any other form of `CompoundButton`. For example, neither `Switch` nor its `CompoundButton` superclass have any methods annotated with `@android.view.RemotableViewMethod` in [the Android 10 source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/tree/android-vts-10.0_r1/core/java/android/widget). A manufacturer might have tweaked things for their own benefit, but I would not assume that `Switch` is usable in `RemoteViews` in all Android devices.

Comment: So theres no way to make a toggle in a notification?

Comment: @LinS: You can have a `Button` or `ImageButton` in your `RemoteViews`. When the user clicks the button, the work triggered by your `PendingIntent` could change the `Button` caption or the `ImageButton` image to reflect a new state. Or, you could use a regular notification (without `RemoteViews`) and update the caption and icon associated with an `Action`. Those would be your primary options.

Comment: Yes, but what about when the button is clicked a second time? how would I preform another action, like a toggle?

Comment: @LinS: "but what about when the button is clicked a second time?" -- you would change the image or caption again. For example, each time you update the image or caption, you could replace the `PendingIntent` with a new one representing the new action that you wish to perform.